# Eclipse Luna Console View - how to lock Console View to console output

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse Luna I opened two Console Views. I attached output from a external build tool to the first one and Liferay server output to the second one. Whenever I run the external build tool, both Console Views start to display the output of the external Build tool and I have to manually switch the content of the second Console View every time. Is it possible to bound the Console View with the specific output permanently? I did not find this feature in the Eclipse documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question, there is a button on the console window which is "Show console on any output":

[image]

Enable this button on the console you want to capture, and disable it ***and the button next to it***, (which is "Show console on any error") for the console you don't want to show.  This usually works for me on Luna SR1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this did not work yesterday. But as I'm not able to reproduce this, I'm starting to think, that it was just a bug between my chair and my keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

There is a button with a "+" sign on the top right. click it to open a new console.
Once you have two consoles, use the Pin console (console with a board pin icon on the top right) button to pin the newly opened console to the liferay server console.